# My Delete Query is not being working

Tags: c#

I,m designing a CMS(campus Management System) and i wana delete some record...but its neither working nor generate any error...just return zero in "result " varaiable mentioned in code

```
public void DeleteAnnouncement(BusinessObject bo)
    {
        string ConnStr = Connection();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "Delete from Anouncement where AnnouncementID=@i";


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("i", bo.A_ID);


        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("\tAnnouncement Deleted");
            Console.WriteLine("\t============================================\n\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your spelling - table name 'Anouncement' but id is 'AnnouncementID', here 'nn' - is it correct?

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint, examine `bo.A_ID` value, check if your table has a record with `AnnouncementID` equal to that value. It's normal `ExecuteNonQuery` to return 0 if there is no matching record.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("i", bo.A_ID);
```

You're missing "@" in front of parameter name.

```
Correct: SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@i", bo.A_ID);
```

Comment: Althogh it dooesn't matter but i tried and Its really not working, as far as table name 'Anouncement' is concernen, its id is 'AnnouncementID'...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and deletes a record from `Anouncement` table, if `AnnouncementID` matches with the value of `bo.A_ID`, if value of `bo.A_ID` doesn't match with `AnnouncementID`, `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns `0`. If it's not deleting that means `AnnouncementID` doesn't match with the value of `bo.A_ID`.

But I suggest improve you code through `using` statement, this `using` statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while methods on the object are called.

```
string ConnStr = Connection();
string query = "Delete from Anouncement where AnnouncementID=@i";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
{
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
     {
         try
            {
                SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("i", bo.A_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                conn.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine 
                    ("\n\n\t============================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tAnnouncement Deleted");
                    Console.WriteLine 
                    ("\t============================================\n\n");
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //Do your exception handling work
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Either debug the code or run SQL profiler to identify the value of "bo.A_ID".